# Выровнять текст кнопки в Android?

Tags: android

Есть кнопка. Вот разметка:

```
<Button
            android:layout_width="300dp"
            android:layout_height="45dp"
            android:text="О КОМПАНИИ"
            android:textColor="#FAFAFA"
            android:textSize="22dp"
            android:background="#2450A9"
            android:id="@+id/button2" />
```

Только текст кнопки находится по центру, как выровнять по левому краю?

Comment: Может начнем сначала с "выравнивания" русского?

Comment: точно так же, как и в `TextView`, и вообще где либо в `Android`

Answer (score 7):

Свойство[`android:gravity`](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/view/Gravity.html) отвечает за сиё

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="45dp"
    android:background="#2450A9"
    android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
    android:text="О КОМПАНИИ"
    android:textColor="#FAFAFA"
    android:textSize="22dp" />
```